What happens if you're prevented from directing Blast Globes to a target the turn after you activate them?
Blast Globes can be found in the Magic Item Compendium page 152.

BLAST GLOBES
Price (Item Level): 8,000 gp (11th)
Body Slot: — (held)
Caster Level: 11th
Aura: Moderate; (DC 20) evocation
Activation: Standard (command); see text
Weight: 1 lb.
Dozens of smaller glass spheres comprise this fist-sized orb. The
flicker of a small flame seems to reflect from deep within.
When you activate a set of blast globes, the transparent globes
separate and begin circling each other. One round after they activate,
you can direct the globes to strike (as a group) any location within
400 feet as a free action. The globes then move to that location and
create an explosion in a 20-foot-radius spread. Any creature in the
area takes 10d6 points of fire damage and 2d6 points of sonic damage,
is deafened for 2d6 rounds, and is pushed 1d6 squares away from the
center of the blast. A successful DC 15 Reflex save halves the fire
damage and negates the push, while a successful DC 15 Fortitude save
negates the deafening effect.
After exploding, the globes reform in your hands or at your feet (if
your hands are full). This ability functions once per day.
Prerequisites: Craft Wondrous Item, fireball, shout.
Cost to Create: 4,000 gp, 320 XP, 8 days.

What happens if the user chooses not to direct the globes to a target on the next turn or are otherwise prevented from doing so (due to unconsciousness, etc.)?  Do they harmlessly deactivate? If so is the charge used up?  Do they detonate in place?  Do they simply wait indefinitely to be directed to a target?

You have quoted the full and complete record of any and all guidance Wizards of the Coast had to offer on the blast globes for D&D 3.5e (they previously appeared in the 2e supplement Secrets of the Magister). As there is no information on what happens if you don’t direct the blast globes in your quote, there is therefore no information on what happens in all of 3.5e. This will necessarily require a DM ruling, and it’s basically going to come down to what the DM thinks is appropriate for a 8,000-gp item. Absolutely nothing in the game provides even a hint of what the answer “should” be.

It’s too late for me to do it tonight, but at some point I hope to check Secrets of the Magister to see if it can suggest answers to either of these questions—would not object if anyone wants to beat me to it and save me the effort.

Can you think of any other item or spell that has a similar two-stage usage with better language?  Nothing came immediately to my mind, and it's not something that's easily searchable (hence my question here).

@Kuro_Neko I’m sure there are, but nothing comes to mind immediately off the top of my head. I’m even more certain that there are spells that work like this, where you cast the spell and then for a while afterward you have an attack you can use (either for as long as the duration lasts or until you’ve used it a certain number of times). Light of Lunda from Spell Compendium for one example, though it’s not alone. And that’s actually the problem: they all specify this kind of thing differently. There isn’t a “standard” here we can assume for the blast globes.

(That should be light of Lunia, not “Lunda.” I even looked it up, since all I could remember was that it was “light of [something],” and still managed to typo it. Too late to edit, though.)

An aside: I think that, technically, the globes could be even dumber: based on the way the item is presented, only the "reform in your hands" ability functions once per day. If you take the standard and subsequent free action to activate the globes a second (or more) time per day, you just have to retrieve them yourself from wherever they unleashed their explosion if you want to do it again. Which is, I think, maybe okay? It means that someone who survives the globes' explosion could then hurl them back—and that's hilarious.

Language precedent in 3.5 suggests they remain active and await a command.
Firstly, there is no mentioned way for the spheres to "deactivate" other than reforming after exploding.  There is no mention of a time limit, no command word or procedure to turn them off, nothing.  Therefore, assuming they deactivate if left alone would require expanding the rules.
Second, they clearly must move to their target before exploding, so they can't explode in place.  The phrasing of "[t]he globes then move to that location and create an explosion" ties the globes exploding directly to the globes moving.  Since they are not ordered to move to the target, and giving an order is the only way to move them to a target, they do not explode in place.
The only remaining possibility is that the globes remain active.
That does leave the possibility, however, that the globes just keep spinning forever and never accept a command after the first round.  While you could make an argument that this is the strict rules-as-written interpretation, there are two main reasons I would personally not agree with it:

These items are reasonably expensive.  If there was a very real possiblity of the item being completely invalidated by a single, simple misuse, it would be spelled out more clearly.  It would also not be so expensive - in order for this item to be reasonably competitive with the Necklace of Fireballs, a similar item that can be used many times per day, it needs to be reusable.
Many other instances of similar wording are used throughout the system, where "can" really means "gains the ability to."  This can be found in tons of class abilities, such as the paladin's Remove Disease which states that "[a]t 6th level, a paladin can produce a remove disease effect[...]."  Nobody is seriously arguing that a 7th level paladin can no longer do this.  If the globes were not meant to function in the same way, they would have borrowed wording from Delayed Blast Fireball or similar and put an explicit cutoff on when you can command them.

This also personally strikes me as the most elegant solution in regards to providing a ruling as a DM for players.  The globes becoming inoperable, losing a charge, or exploding in the players' faces comes across as needlessly harsh for an item that is clearly designed to be very reliable.

I agree with this answer, except that I feel “The only remaining possibility is that the globes remain active,” is highly misleading. That simply isn’t true: the rules don’t allow that any more than they support having the item’s daily activation be wasted. You give a decent rationale for preferring the interpretation that allows it to continue to be used, but your earlier statement makes it sound much stronger than “both of these are possible, but I think this one is better for reasons” which is the actual situation we have here.

In short, your answer—in reality—is that the rules are broken in some way and we have to fix them, and there are a few apparent candidates for fixes that are all equally “not actually what the rules say,” but you imply that one of them actually is supported as the fix (it isn’t).

@KRyan I'll clarify the intent of that statement: there are 4 possible rules interpretations as I see it.  I think self-destruction and deactivation are both explicitly not supported by the rules.  The alternative is two similar options: that they stay active and take commands, or that they stay active and don't take commands.  My only definite statement was in ruling out the first two, as it requires fewer (albeit not no) assumptions to say that the globes remain active.  Then between the latter two possibilities I gave my reasoning and rationale, while aknowledging that it is still vague.

@KRyan Which, I suppose, could be rephrased as something along the lines of "there's not a perfect answer because the item is poorly written, but there are two interpretations that are less wrong than the alternatives, and of the two, one is a lot more elegant."

The rules are explicit about “One round,” while the failure to deactivate and/or explode is assumed from the lack of a rule, so I strongly disagree that the former is in any way less “explicitly not supported” than the latter. You’re arbitrarily deciding one is “explicit” while the other is “technically true, but not really”—but that’s not really an accurate description of the situation. Both are unsupported. We just have to pick one.

Also, on which to pick, consider that if you can direct the orbs as a free action at any point after activating, you could activate at the beginning of the day, and then enjoy a free-action 12d6 blast in a large area with add-on effects. I might still buy an argument that that’s appropriate for 8k, maybe, but I don’t think the item guidelines would agree with you.

Even if we assume 'stays active until directed', there's nothing in the language that even hints that the item follows you around once activated. And you're not still holding on to it, as it explicitly states that the globes separate and start orbiting each other.  So even assuming that interpretation, you could only really use the 'activate in the morning then fire any time later' if you were relatively stationary the whole day.
